# Como somar os valores inseridos no while em Java?

Tags: java, while

Estou aprendendo Java sozinho e cheguei na parte de estruturas de repetição.
Me deparei com a seguinte atividade:

> Utilizando a estrutura de repetição WHILE, implemente um programa em
> Java para ler o peso e o gênero (masculino = 1 / feminino = 2) de um grupo
> de 5 pessoas e ao término mostre:
>
> - O número de homens e o número de mulheres do grupo;
> - A média dos pesos do grupo;
> - Indicar o gênero que teve a maior ocorrência (homens ou mulheres);

Não faço ideia de como consigo somar, por exemplo, o peso de todos para conseguir a média.
Isso é o que eu tenho por enquanto:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AEDSCARLOS {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pessoas = 0;
    int peso = 0;
    int genero = 0;

    System.out.println("Número de pessoas no grupo: ");
    pessoas = scan.nextInt();

    while (pessoas > 0) {
      System.out.printf("Digite o peso do integrante %d: \n", pessoas);
      peso = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.printf("Digite o gênero do integrante \n", pessoas);
      genero = scan.nextInt();
      pessoas--;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro crie uma nova variável `totalPessoas` que vai receber o mesmo valor de `pessoas`, exemplo:

```
totalPessoas = pessoas;
```

Essa atribuição vai acontecer antes da linha:

```
while(pessoas > 0){
```

Após a linha:

```
peso=scan.nextInt();
```

Adicione:

```
pesoTotal += peso;
```

E para chegar no valor da média, fora do corpo do `while`, utilize o código:

```
media = pesoTotal / totalPessoas;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentei escrever um código com uma solução diferente e usando alguns recursos mais avançados (como stream) para que caso tu não conheça possa ir atrás e aprender =)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Pode ajustar as listas para trabalhar com array caso seja necessario
    List<Double> masculino = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> feminino = new ArrayList<>();

    int quantidadeDePessoas = 0;

    while (quantidadeDePessoas < 5) {

        System.out.printf("Digite o gênero");
        int genero = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Digite o peso");
        double peso = sc.nextDouble();

        if (genero == 1) {
            masculino.add(peso);
        } else if (genero == 2) {
            feminino.add(peso);
        }

        quantidadeDePessoas++;
    }

    System.out.println("Quantidade masculino: " + masculino.size());
    System.out.println("Quantidade feminino: " + feminino.size());

    //Java 8 - pode ser substituido por um for/while repetindo pelo tamanho da lista
    Double totalPesoMasculino = masculino.stream().mapToDouble(peso -> peso).sum();

    Double totalPesoFeminino = feminino.stream().mapToDouble(peso -> peso).sum();

    System.out.println("Media masculino: " + totalPesoMasculino / masculino.size());
    System.out.println("Media feminino: " + totalPesoFeminino / feminino.size());

    //Operador ternario
    String maiorOcorrencia = masculino.size() > feminino.size() ? "masculino" : "feminino";

    System.out.println("Maior ocorrencia: " + maiorOcorrencia);

}
```